# Overloading best practice

Tags: c#, overloading

I have two static methods that I want to use for error handling. One of which passes the exception object and the other is just used if needing to report an error which would be a text based message (string errorMessage).

The code within the two methods is pretty much the same with the exception of how the message is build up and sent to a log file. How can I refactor this so that I'm not duplicating code?

```
public static void ReportError(Exception exceptionRaised, string reference, string customMessage, bool sendEmail)
{
    // get filename
    // check if logfile exists, blah, blah
    // build up message from exception, reference & custom message using string builder
    // save message
    // email error (if set)
}

public static void ReportError(string errorMessage, string reference, bool sendEmail)
{
    // get filename
    // check if logfile exists, blah, blah
    // build up message from errorMessage & reference string builder
    // save message
    // email error (if set)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution would be to extract the duplicate code into it's own method, like this:

```
public static void ReportError(Exception exceptionRaised, string reference, string customMessage, bool sendEmail)
{
    // build up message from exception, reference & custom message using string builder
    ProcessError(Message, SendEmail)
}

public static void ReportError(string errorMessage, string reference, bool sendEmail)
{
    // build up message from errorMessage & reference string builder
    ProcessError(Message, SendEmail)
}

private static void ProcessError(string message, bool sendEmail)
{
    // get filename
    // check if logfile exists, blah, blah
    // save message
    // email error (if set)
}
```

This is certainly not the most elegant way to do it, but it is a start ;-)

Comment: Personally I prefer this way of working, hence why it's my answer too. I don't like having to pass through `""` and `null` values into methods, even if it is hidden from the development user. So +1.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. This looks like my preferred way as I also don't like sending nulls. I have taken note of other comments and have rearranged the order of the parameters and have renamed string errorMessage to be string customMessage - which is more consistent with the other method.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9):

Seeing as all you're doing differently is building up a custom message in the first method, change your first method to pass the custom exception through the plain text error message method instead:

```
public static void ReportError(Exception exceptionRaised, string reference, 
    string customMessage, bool sendEmail)
{
    string errorMessage = BuildMessage(exceptionRaised, customMessage);
    ReportError(errorMessage, reference, sendEmail);
}
```

*Disclaimer: Not entirely sure if this will work. It depends how you build up the error message.*

**EDIT:**

Or you could add a third overload:

```
private static void ReportError(string completeException, bool sendEmail)
{
     // Do what needs to be done.
}
```

And then your methods could just both build up the exception message and pass that string and `sendEmail` boolean to the third overload.

Comment: I personally prefer this one over the accepted answer, because it generates a clearer image of how the two variants relate to each other.

Comment: After thinking about it for a minute, I also find this solution better that my answer. (As I said, my method *'is certainly not the most elegant way to do it, but it is a start'*). You did not only start from the same point I did, you walked the way a little further. +1, and I hope the OP accepts your answer!

Answer (score 5):

Can you just make the overload with fewer parameters call the one with more, passing in `null` or "" as the custom message?

```
public static void ReportError(string errorMessage,
                               string reference,
                               bool sendEmail)
{
    ReportError(errorMessage, reference, null, sendEmail);
}
```

Note that if you're using C# 4, you could do this without overloading, using an optional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When overloading methods, make sure that the first parameters always are the same. It's a bit confusing otherwise. In your case, make the exception the last parameter.

```
public static void ReportError(string customMessage, string reference, bool sendEmail, Exception exceptionRaised)
```

As for code duplication. Make both methods call a third protected method which does the actual handling.
The exception method can format the exception and add it to the message parameter before calling the third method.

Comment: +1 for keeping the parameters aligned. Sometimes I forget that the a class interface is consumed (i.e. *read*) by humans, not computers. A lesson worth to remember...

Answer (score 0):

```
void report(Exception e)
{
  //convert exception to plain text
  string text = e.ToString();
  //re-use the other overload
  report(text);
}

void report(string text)
{
  ...etc...
}
```

A more complicated version:

```
delegate string GetString();

public void report(Exception e)
{
  GetString getString = delegate() { return e.ToString(); }
  report(getText);
}

public void report(string text)
{
  GetString getString = delegate() { return text; }
  report(getText);
}

void report(GetString getString)
{
  ...etc...
  string text = getString();
  ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good but I thought I would add something to avoid that I have come across that tends to be a maintenance pain in the ...

```
public void report(string text)
{
   ...
   report(text,defaultvalue);
}

public void report(string text, string email)
{
   ...
   report(text,email,null);
}

public void report(string text, string email, List<string> errors)
{
   ...
}
...
etc.
```

This tends to be very anoying when you have to refactor all these methods just cause you want to change a parameter in one of the methods.